# Solving for a variable on both sides of fraction

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't figure out how to solve for this:

$$1.34 = \frac{6400 + 0.477t}{2388 + t}$$

I tried to multiply by t/1 but that only gotme into more trouble, does anyone know how to get started?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Multiply both sides by $2388+t$ then isolate the terms with $t$ in them on one side, leaving the remaining terms on the other side. It should be clear how to solve from here.